# jquery click not binding even when using ".on"

Tags: jquery, click, bind

This is something I've done 100 times, but I can't spot why it's not binding.
I'm creating a itemized list from a TAFFY database.

```
// get matching data from tfPLdata
var ts="";
var match=0;
tfPLdata({"vType":{likenocase:vType},"vSubType":{likenocase:vSubType}}).each(function (record,recordnumber) {   
    match++;
    ts+="<div class='vWRAP' id='vh_"+recordnumber+"'>";
        ts+="<div class='vTN'>"+record["vTypeName"]+"</div>";
        ts+="<div class='vP'>"+record["vPrice"]+"</div>";
    ts+="</div>";
});
```

the result looks like this

```
<div class='vWRAP' id='vh_0'>
    <div class='vTN'>my corn seed 2</div>
    <div class='vP'>165.00</div>
</div>
<div class='vWRAP' id='vh_1'>
    <div class='vTN'>my corn seed 1</div>
    <div class='vP'>150.00</div>
</div>
```

then I'm trying to bind CLICK to the class .vWRAP

```
$(".vWRAP").click(function(){
        console.log("test");
});
```

but it just doesn't fire.

Why?

========================================

I added the code:

```
$(function() {
      $(".vWRAP").each(function(){
        console.log( $(this).attr("id") );
        $(this).click(function(){
            console.log("test");
        });
      });
});
```

and it correctly shows the ID for each .vWRAP.
It still won't bind "click" however.

Comment: Are the divs added dynamically after the page is loaded?

Comment: yes: dynamically after page is loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume your elements are being added dynamically. To bind click to dynamic elements use the jQuery [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.vWRAP', function() {
        console.log("test");
    });
});
```

Also just incase you didn't know `$(function () { ... });` is a short hand for [document ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) `$(document).ready(function () { ... });`.

I also use `jQuery` instead of `$` because it avoids conflict issues.

Comment: Thank you. 
I am adding dynamically. 
(I had to remove the open-parenthesis before 2nd "function" btw)
This still does not work.

Comment: Sorry the `(` was a typo, edited now. If this code doesn't work then there is something wrong with your code.

Comment: What was happening really didn't have to do with the fact that the data was dynamic. The element that fires the display of #vHelper lost focus and it was going away before the click had a chance to fire.